# to store very huge value in java. 2power31

Tags: java, long-integer, biginteger

I'm working on a question where I need to store the number 1101001000100000.... till `Math.pow(2,31)` I'm wondering which function can be used to do it. I have tried with `long`, `BigInteger` but they are throwing an error.

My code:

```
Long a = (long) 1;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String z="";
sb.append(1);
for(Long i=(long) 1;i<Math.pow(2, 31)-1;i++) {
    a= (long) (Math.pow(10, i));
    z=Long.toString(a);
    sb.append(z);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to imagine an English class which would fail to teach the basics like that "I" is always capitalized, or that the word is "I'm" not "im", or that sentences start with a capital letter. Trying, but failing. Please take the time to use proper capitalization and puncutation when asking for help.

Comment: *"...but they are throwing an error."* ***What*** error?

Comment: Your code is going a heck of a lot further than 2^31. You have a loop where `i` will end up being 2^31 - 1, but then you do this: `Math.pow(10, i)`. So your biggest number will be 10^(2^31).

Comment: java heap size: out of memory

Comment: yes you are right @T J crowder. how can i hold that huge number ?

Answer (score 2):

@T.J. Crowder was alluding to the staggering size of your number and the consequences it has on storage, especially since you are trying to save it as a string. The number grows to over 2 billion digits long with say 2 bytes for every digit. But since you are appending the strings you have an arithmetic series to calculate the length. At a rough guess for a Sunday night it looks like total characters of the order of 2 bytes x (2 billion x 2 billion) / 2 which is about 4 billion gigabytes.

Comment: That is ~4 Exabytes of RAM memory.  In one machine addressable by one CPU.  Good luck with that :-)